# libnet.h no such file or directory when building dsploit

Tags: android, ubuntu, native

I was trying to build [this](https://github.com/evilsocket/dsploit/tree/master/dSploit) project on my eclipse. It's using libnet library so i install the `libnet-dev` on my ubuntu.

However, i still got no such file or directory error in `arp.h` (JNI) on this line:

```
  #include <libnet.h>
```

I have also tried to compile the libnet by myself using [this](https://github.com/tux-mind/libnet) source and put all of the directory its generated on the libnet folder in the project.

Please help me out, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source repository, it seems that the [`arpspoof` Makefile](https://github.com/evilsocket/dsploit/blob/master/dSploit/jni/arpspoof/Android.mk) does not look for `libnet` from the system. Instead, the dSploit repository includes libnet as a Git submodule. Did you clone recursively? (`git clone --recursive ...`).

If you did not, change to the dSploit directory and run:

```
git submodule update
```

To fetch all the submodules.